# requirejs angularjs controller not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

When i try to load a controller dynamically, I'm having the following error: 
sideCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

but for page1, the code works fine.
Here is my code:

main.js:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: ['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min', 'lib/jquery/jquery_2.0.0.min.js'],
        angular: ['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min', 'lib/angular/angular_1.2.16.min'],
        angularRoute: ['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-route.min', 'lib/angular-route/angular-route_1.2.16.min']
    },
    shim: {
        'angular' : {'exports' : 'angular'},
        'angularRoute': ['angular']
    },
    deps: ['app']
});
```

config.js:

```
define([],function(){
  function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/page1', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/page1.html', 
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/page2', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/page2.html',         
        resolve: {
            load: function($q, $route, $rootScope) {

                var deferred = $q.defer();

                var dependencies = [
                    'sideCtrl.js'
                ];

                require(dependencies, function () {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    deferred.resolve();
                    });
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
      })
      .otherwise({redirectTo: '/page1'});
  }
  config.$inject=['$routeProvider'];

  return config;
});
```

app.js

```
/*global require*/
'use strict';

define([
    'angular','angularRoute', 'mainCtrl', 'config'
    ], function (angular, angularRoute,mainCtrl,config) {
        var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
        app.config(config);
        app.controller('mainCtrl', mainCtrl);


        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);       
        return app; 
});
```

sideCtrl.js:

```
"use strict";
define(['app'], function (app) {

    app.controller('sideCtrl', ['$scope',
        function ($scope) {
            console.log("hello world");
            $scope.names="krish";
            console.log("sideCtrl calling");
        }
    ]);
    console.log(app);
    return app;
});
```

page2.html

```
<div ng-controller="sideCtrl">
 asdasdas
    {{names}}

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding controller dynamically requires you to register it using current active provider, therefore you cannot register it using regular "app.controller", what you need to do is register it via **$controllerProvider.register**

Best regards

Comment: If I do that, this is the error: $controllerProvider is not defined

Comment: you need to inject it first ? I do this on my config `app.provider('resolver',['$controllerProvider','$compileProvider','$filterProvider','$provide',

    function($controllerProvider,$compileProvider,$filterProvider,$provide){
        angular.register = {
           controller:$controllerProvider.register,
           directive:$compileProvider.directive,
           filter:$filterProvider.register,
           factory:$provide.factory,
           service:$provide.service,
           constant:$provide.constant
        }; }])`

Comment: okay, using app.controllerProvider instead of $controllerProvider worked for me. Thanks a lot.